# Toshiba Satellite L755 not functioning properly while charging

Tags: troubleshooting, charging, toshiba-laptop

While charging my laptop, the touchpad becomes very jumpy and sometimes does not even go in the direction moved. The computer itself also runs very erratically. While it does this, my computer switches between charging and not charging, even though the cable is still connected.
The charging light blinks erratically.

I'll admit, I have dropped it once, but that was several months ago and there have been no problems of this sort. I am running Windows 7, and this computer is over a year old.

**EDIT :**

I have found that something that stops this problem is to have the adapter already plugged in and connected to my laptop. I don't know if this makes it easier to diagnose.

Well, now it is not working altogether. I have tried different outlets, but none of them charge it. It has run out of battery, and is now acting very strangely when I try to charge it: The charging light flickers, then after a short while it flickers while the next two flash.

More info: I have not been able to try another adapter, but when I tried to have the power cable in without the battery, the plugged-in light turns on and is steady. Trying to turn it on makes things like the caps lock and the numlock LEDs flash, almost as if it was trying to turn on. I therefore believe the adapter isn't supplying enough power for the computer to run (although this wouldn't explain the weird behavior when the battery is in). What I am going to try is leaving it plugged in overnight, and see if that charges the battery at all.

Comment: How was it dropped (from your lap, off a table, onto a hard floor, etc)?  Where did it land (on its side, on the edge or corner, on the lid or bottom)?  Was it in use or open at the time?  Was the DC Jack/power adapter port impacted?  Are you still using the original power adapter?  There could be a loose screw within the casing, or the DC jack could be damaged to where the power adapter cord is not sitting inside the jack properly, or it could even be something else.  Does the laptop operate properly if you remove the battery, plug it in, and power it on?

Comment: Is your computer plugged straight into the wall, or do you have a surge protector or battery backup in line?  Although I would think @BonGart has you covered mostly here - I have seen PCs/Phones/Tablets run like that when they have dirty power coming in (could be a function of the items Bon mentioned above).

Comment: Hmm... It only seems to happen on some outlets. It landed on it's corner by the adapter, and that are does seem to be somewhat damaged, but this only appears to be on the casing. It was closed (standby) at the time. The jack doesn't sit in it properly, but moving it/securing it changed nothing. I am using the original adapter. I am somewhat reluctant to try and open it up to look inside, though.

Answer (score 1):

From the information in the question and the comments, I believe that you need to take the laptop to a repair shop, have them open it, and have them examine the DC jack and how well it is (not) mounted to the casing anymore.

From [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008A3KHQ6)
[image]
There are other images you can search for... but in general, for a few years now, Toshiba has moved away from the DC jack being mounted directly to the motherboard, and instead has the DC jack attached to a harness.  This reduces the amount of damage to motherboards in cases of DC jack damage, and makes them easier to replace... as opposed to replacing the jack and the whole motherboard as used to happen in some cases.

I can't say without looking at yours, but from what you say in that it landed near the DC jack, it does seem to be somewhat damaged in the casing, and the jack doesn't sit in the whole properly... I think the unit needs to be opened and the jack assembly needs to be examined if not replaced.  Granted, if it landed on the adapter plug itself while it was plugged in, the end of the adapter cable might be damaged... requiring the replacement of the DC adapter instead... but with damage to the casing, at the very LEAST the unit needs to be taken apart and examined.  For all we know, the DC jack is loose, and making contact with the motherboard, causing intermittent shorts.